# Types of Process Peak Memory Usage

Tags: c#, .net, memory-management, process

The [`Process`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Diagnostics.Process%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) type has the following three properties.

- [`PeakPagedMemorySize64`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.peakpagedmemorysize64%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)
- [`PeakVirtualMemorySize64`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.peakvirtualmemorysize64%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)
- [`PeakWorkingSet64`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.peakworkingset64%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

What are the meanings of paged memory, virtual memory, and working set?

In laymen's terms, if I want to report the "Peak amount of memory used by the process," which value (or combination of values) is appropriate?

Comment: Your links gives full explanation.

Comment: @HamletHakobyan I read them thoroughly prior to posting.

Answer (score 3):

When your system has X MB memory, but your application uses > X MB memory, *virtual memory* is used to accommodate. In short, it's just a way to spoof RAM addresses against file system. Because the working set of memory is now larger than the actual installed RAM, *paging* is used to move data between RAM and disk storage... Incidentally this is why virtual memory is slow... disk paging.

Anyway, your definitions:

- PeakPagedMemorySize64 = the max amount of memory used by the process in the virtual memory paging file. As we discussed, virtual memory is paged. A page is a set of memory used at one time.
- PeakVirtualMemorySize64 = the max amount of virtual memory used by the process (should be >= PeakPagedMemorySize64).
- PeakWorkingSet64 = the max amount of physical memory used by the process.

It will be really hard to report adequately on memory usage, since while `PeakVirtualMemorySize64` and `PeakWorkingSet64` may each be `100`, it may be that the first was 100 when the second was 25 and the second was 100 when the first was 25, so the real max was actually 125 and not 200.. However your only real measurement derivable from these properties would be to add the two together for an estimate (or report on them individually).